# How to get message data from the human task event listener in wso2bps

Tags: listener, wso2

When a human task instance is created, i can get task information in the event listener, like task id, task subject, task owner, etc. Sample code is [here](http://tryitnw.blogspot.com/2013/05/humantask-event-listeners-wso2-bps.html). But how can i get the task message data(or so called payload)? I tried to use the task id to query database in the listener:

```
select * from ht_message where message_type='INPUT' and  task_id = 7001
```

But no results returned. In fact the task has not been stored into database at this point.

I also tried to sleep the current thread for several seconds to waiting for the task data been saved to database. But it turns out the save operation was done after the listener is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by modifying the source code.

1. Add a field called "body" and its getter/setter method to **TaskInfo.java**
   [image: Changes to TaskInfo.java]
2. Add a getData() method to interface **MessageDAO.java**
   [image: Changes to MessageDAO.java]
3. Implement getData() in the **Message.java**
   [image: Changes to Message.jara]
4. Populate message data to task info in **CommonTaskUtil.java**
   [image: Changes to CommonTaskUtil.java]

Then in the task lister i can get the message data by

```
String messageData = taskEventInfo.getTaskInfo().getBody();
```